# Not sure why If Statement is not working. (Pygame)

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, pygame

Ok so now when I press E at "start.png" it jumps to "cele.png" when I would expect it to go to "new.png".  I want it to start at "start.png" then when you press E it should change to "new.png" and if you press E again while background is "new.png" then it should change to "cele.png"  Thanks!

```js
#import library
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
 
#initialize the game
pygame.init()
width, height = 1000, 800
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Pygame Window")
 
#load images
bg_filename = "start.png"
background = pygame.image.load(bg_filename)

#keep looping through
while 1:

    #clear the screen before drawing it again
    screen.fill(0)
    #draw the screen elements
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    #update the screen
    pygame.display.flip()
    #loop through the events
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        #start to new
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_e:
                if bg_filename == "start.png":
                    bg_filename = "new.png"
                    background = pygame.image.load(bg_filename)

        #new to cele 
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_e:
                if bg_filename == "new.png":
                    bg_filename = "cele.png"
                    background = pygame.image.load(bg_filename)

        #check if the event is the X button 
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            #if it is quit the game
            pygame.quit() 
            exit(0)
```

Comment: Instead of writing "blah", why not describe what happens when you run the code in more details? And where you think the problem is? Details that might seem unimportant to you may be important to us, or even the reason for your problems, so that's why it's always better to include to many details than the opposite (but with code it's kind of the opposite, only include the relevant and nothing more, to begin with, add more when asked).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg this is a [dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998066/pygame-how-to-do-if-statement-correctly?noredirect=1#comment48134954_29998066).

Comment: You are trying to test a string for equality to an image object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surfaces doesn't have an object for retrieving the file name, but maybe you could use another variable to hold the file name?

```
#load images
bg_filename = "start.png"
background = pygame.image.load(bg_filename)

#keep looping through
while 1:
    #clear the screen before drawing it again
    screen.fill(0)
    #draw the screen elements
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    #update the screen
    pygame.display.flip()
    #loop through the events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_e:
                if bg_filename == "start.png":
                    bg_filename = "new.png"
                    background = pygame.image.load(bg_filename)
```